# Accessing localhost using ip

Tags: localhost, intranet

I am running google app engine locally and it runs on port 8080. I can access it from the browser using 'localhost:8080' or '127.0.0.1:8080'. But I cannot access it using the ip of the machine even locally. Any pointers?

Update:Solved it by binding the ip to 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the software must be binding directly to 127.0.0.1.  You can not connect to it on any other address, even if it is on the same machine.

You might be able to reconfigure it to listen on 0.0.0.0, but that may open you up to security risks.

Comment: Thanks. I want to access this from another machine in the intranet. Using the ip does not work. I am running on windows and have disabled the firewall. Also have checked the open ports using netstat and it says 8080 is listening. Any pointers?

Comment: I gave you a pointer, but apparently you need someone to read the docs for you...

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver.html#Command_Line_Arguments

--address=...
The host address to use for the server. You may need to set this to be able to access the development server from another computer on your network. An address of 0.0.0.0 allows both localhost access and hostname access. Default is localhost.